# Show that $\|AB\|_p \le \|A\|_p \|B\|_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

> Show that $\|AB\|_p \le \|A\|_p \|B\|_p$ for any $p \in [1, \infty)$.

The definition I have is that $\|A\|_p = \underset{x \not= 0}{\sup}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} = \underset{\|x\|_p = 1}{\max}\|Ax\|_p$.

According to the definition:
$$\|AB\|_p = \sup_{x \not = 0}\frac{\|ABx\|_p}{\|x\|_p} = \sup_{x \not = 0}\frac{\|ABx\|_p\|Bx\|_p}{\|Bx\|_p\|x\|_p} = \sup_{x \not = 0}\frac{\|Bx\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \frac{\|ABx\|_p}{\|Bx\|_p} \\ \le \sup_{x \not = 0}\frac{\|Bx\|_p}{\|x\|_p} \sup_{Bx \not = 0}\frac{\|ABx\|_p}{\|Bx\|_p} = \|B\|_p\|A\|_p.$$

Now I don't understand the inequality part. Why is $\underset{Bx \not= 0}{\sup}\dfrac{\|ABx\|_p}{\|Bx\|_p} \le \underset{x \not= 0}{\sup}\dfrac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}$?

Comment: You are taking the supremum over the range of $B$ which may be smaller than the whole space.

Comment: Also, this proof has some issues. What happens if $B(x)=0$? then you can't divide by its norm. From the supremum definition it should be clear that for any operator $T$, and any $x$, one has $\lVert T(x)\rVert\leq \lVert T\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$. Writing things in this multiplicative form avoids any division by zero issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your definition, if $x\neq 0$, then
$\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\leq \|A\|_p $.
It follows that
$$\|Ax\|_p\leq\|A\|_p\|x\|_p\qquad \forall x.$$
Using the above,for $x\neq 0$, we have
$$\frac{\|ABx\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\leq \frac{\|A\|_p\|Bx\|_p}{\|x\|_p}\leq \frac{\|A\|_p\|B\|_p\|x\|_p}{\|x\|_p}=\|A\|_p\|B\|_p,$$
which implies $\|AB\|_p\leq \|A\|_p\|B\|_p$.

Answer (score 2):

What the comment says is the following:

> If $A\subseteq B$ then $\sup\{x:x\in A \}\leq \sup\{x : x\in B \}$.

Consider $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ and  $N,M\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, then we have $\Gamma=\{Mx\in \mathbb{R}^n\}\backslash \{0\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}$, therefore $A=\{Ny:y\in \Gamma\}\subseteq \{Nx:x\in \mathbb{R}^n\backslash \{0\}\} =B$ for which $\sup A\leq \sup B$.